# create a time based on seconds in c#

Tags: c#

If i have a seconds as a int like 70 80 or 2500 how do i show it as a time of format hh:mm:ss using the most easiest way. I know i can make a separate method for it and i did but i wanna check if there is any lib func already available for it. 
THis is the method i created and it works.

```
private void MakeTime(int seconds)
    {
        int min = 0;
        int sec = seconds;
        int hrs = 0;
        if (seconds > 59)
        {
            min = seconds / 60;
            sec = seconds % 60;
        }
        if (min > 59)
        {
            hrs = min / 60;
            min = min % 60;
        }
        string a = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hrs, min, sec);
    }
```

This is the function i am using now. it works but still i have a feeling that a single line call will do this. Any one know of any?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `TimeSpan`

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
```

and

use `t.Hours`, `t.Minutes` and `t.Seconds` to format the string how ever you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).ToString("hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
        string a = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(666);
    string time = ts.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx):

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(70);
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you can't just use DateTime instead, like this?

```
        DateTime t = new DateTime(0);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter # of seconds");
        string userSeconds = Console.ReadLine();
        t = t.AddSeconds(Int32.Parse(userSeconds));
        Console.WriteLine("As HH:MM:SS = {0}:{1}:{2}", t.Hour, t.Minute, t.Second);
```